# Excel: Count sum of cells along a row until a value is found

Tags: excel, math, count, formula, equation

Picture 50 rows that all have a number "4" in it.
However in each row there are 26 columns (A-Z) and the 4 is placed on a different letter in each row.
I need a count of finding the "4" in each row (i.e. if it's "E" that the "4" sits in, the count should be "5".

[image: the 1 should be counted as a 5 because the 4 is 5 cells along]

the 1 should be counted as a 5 because the 4 is 5 cells along

Comment: Rather than "picture" it, is there anything more concrete you can provide?  Like a screenshot.

Comment: @Skin screenshot attached!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your column headings, I think you can just use the **MATCH** function.

```
=MATCH(4,A1:I1)
```

[image: MATCH]

##### Result

[image: Result]

You just need to adapt it to your range.

Comment: No worries, was straight forward in the end.